# What is the difference between 'WCHAR' and 'wchar_t'?

Tags: c++

Is there any practical difference between `WCHAR` and `wchar_t`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, one practical difference would be that `WCHAR` doesn't exist on my platform. For Windows only (and with no intention of ever porting the program to another platform) and with the necessary headers included, it's the same (since `WCHAR` is just a `typedef`).

Comment: so which is recommended to use `WCHAR` or `wchar_t`?

Comment: @Mayur The first sentence of my answer implies that `wchar_t` is recommended. There isn’t really a good reason, other than consistency with internal Windows APIs, to ever use `WCHAR` nowadays. Consider it obsolete.

Answer (score 17):

`wchar_t` is a distinct type, defined by the C++ standard.

`WCHAR` is *non*standard, and as far as I know, exists only on Windows. However, it is simply a `typedef` (or possibly a macro) for `wchar_t`, so it makes no practical difference.

Older versions of MSVC did not have `wchar_t` as a first-class type—instead it was simply a `typedef` for `short`

Most likely, Microsoft introduced `WCHAR` to represent a "wide character type" across any compiler version, whether or not `wchar_t` existed as a native type.

You should use `wchar_t` in your code though. That's what it's for.

Answer (score 5):

Does anybody know how old `WCHAR` is? I would imagine it dates to at least Windows NT 3.1. I'd speculate that when Microsoft started using `WCHAR` in the Windows headers, `wchar_t` was not defined in either the C or C++ standard. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Microsoft is in the unenviable position of having to support declarations and headers that a) must work in either C and C++ ; b) compile under very different architectures (i86, MIPS, PowerPC, Alpha, ...) and c) must be backwards-compatible with source code written for 15+ year old compilers. Plus, any breaking changes and thousands of books, reference manuals, online documentation, etc published over the last two decades would suddenly become WRONG.

`WCHAR` is an interface—once it became published it was written in stone, even if it's not needed for new code.

Answer (score 0):

Practically speaking there isn't much difference.  They both represent the same underlying type.  A 2 byte width value.

LibT will be on shortly to give you the real insane differences between the various platforms an the C++ standard :)

Comment: It's important to note that this is valid on Windows only. WCHAR is a Windows-specific typedef (or is it a #define?), and sizeof(wchar_t) depends on the platform. On Linux (and, IIRC, Solaris), for example, it is 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

typedef wchar_t WCHAR;    // wc,   16-bit UNICODE character

this is defined in winnt.h.So originally it is wchar_t WCHAR is abbrivation to it .You can used wcscat,wcslen etc. functions for both

Answer (score 0):

Official Microsoft docs are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types

> WCHAR  A 16-bit Unicode character. For more information, see Character
> Sets Used By Fonts.
>
> This type is declared in WinNT.h as follows:
>
> typedef wchar_t WCHAR;