# MFC - How to convert WCHAR to CString?

Tags: c++, string, mfc, char, wchar

Is it possible to convert WCHAR to CString? I need to do that, or even convert it to char or char*.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`CString` has constructors and assignment operators that accept `char*` and `wchar_t*` data as input.  So you can assign them directly to `CString`.

If you want to convert `wchar_t*` to `char*` look at `WideCharToMultiByte()`

Answer (score 2):

`CString` is OK with both `CHAR` & `WCHAR`. In other places, for example `std::string` & `std::wstring`, use the MFC String Conversion Macro: `CW2A(pszW)`

```
CHAR B[32]{ "The Matrix Has You" };
WCHAR WB[32]{ L"Wake up, Neo." };
std::string str;
std::wstring wstr{ L"Follow the White Rabbit" };

// std::string from std::wstring:
str = CW2A(wstr.c_str());

// CString (OK with both CHAR & WCHAR):
CString str1{ B };
CString str2{ WB };
CString str3{ str.c_str() };
CString str4{ wstr.c_str() };

// std::string from CString:
str = CW2A(str1);
```

-

The set of MFC generic macros is listed below:

```
A2CW   (LPCSTR)  -> (LPCWSTR)  
A2W    (LPCSTR)  -> (LPWSTR)  
W2CA   (LPCWSTR) -> (LPCSTR)  
W2A    (LPCWSTR) -> (LPSTR)
```

-

[ATL and MFC String Conversion Macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`CString` has constructors which accept `char`, `char*` and `wchar_t`.
(If you do not understand the difference between 'WCHAR' and `wchar_t`, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561839/what-is-the-difference-between-wchar-and-wchar-t) will be a good reference. )

So you can do like this.

```
CString newCString(your_WCHAR);
```

Comment: Could you please add explanation to why this is good solution to the problem.